# delphi create sql select statement at runtime

Tags: sql, delphi, dataset

I am attempting to create a sql statement in XE8 at runtime to search an oracle database based on the value in a textbox. I find multiple different ways that attempt to explain this online, but I am not understanding what it is asking.

I want to search a server based on a select statement and populate TDB components (labels only) based on the data. The furthest I have gotten is to get data populated, but the where

```
' ... somevalue = ' + textbox.text;
```

seems to have no effect.

What components do I need to make this happen? I am connected to the database, and it appears that I can get some kinda data out of it, but I can't seem to figure out how to filter the results. Obviously, I cannot create this sql statement at design time as the value of textbox.text will change depending on the user's input.

Comment: You may want to check **prepared statements** using [TADOQuery](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOQuery.html) or [ZEOSLib](http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Add the code you're using to your q, please.  Readers can't  see your screen.

Comment: Let me rephrase. How do I setup the components so that I can dynamically create a sql statement on the fly that my data aware components update quickly?

Comment: String concatenation doesn't work?

Comment: Without seeing the code it will be hard to give a good answer. Are you refreshing or reopening the query once you have changed the SQL text? My guess is that you are only changing the text but not reopening the query so that the next sql takes effect.

Comment: please don't concatenate your SQL query, use a fixed string with parameters, or else you are open to SQL Injection vulnerabilities...

Comment: It would avoid wasting readers' time if in future you would  post complete example code, not a fragment devoid of context.  You're asking for help f.o.c. here at SO so please at least take the trouble to write a clear question including the relevant code.

Comment: It wasn't a code question. It was a question about how the components went together to even get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was in how to dynamically change what the data aware components got data as it would not always be the same. I had to manually go in and modify their datafield properties. Once I did this, my query functioned correctly.

Comment: This probably worked because modifying the datafield properties will refresh the underlying dataset. See my comment above about the need to refresh the query once you change the SQL text.